# how to retrieve 8 Textviews from layout in array

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 8 Textviews in my layout they are blank right now  I want to get Array of those 8 textivews id's so that I can later setTextView after I randomly choose 8 text out of 15

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public View[] getViewArrays(int resid)
    {
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(resid);

        View[] views = new View[layout.getChildCount()];

        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            views[i] = layout.getChildAt(i);
        }

        return views;
    }

    public int[] getViewIds(int resid)
    {
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(resid);

        int[] ids = new int[layout.getChildCount()];

        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ids[i] = layout.getChildAt(i).getId();
        }

        return ids;
    }
```